# Couldn't pass value to the other webpage in ASP.NET(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameter-passing, html

```
public void Submit1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs E)
{
    string strheadlinesid1 = string.Empty;

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["folder"].ToString())))
        {
            strheadlinesid1 = Request.QueryString["folder"].ToString();

        }
    }

    string URL = "view4.aspx?value="+strheadlinesid1;

    Response.Redirect(URL);
   }
```

This is a function I'm using but when I pass **strheadlinesid1**, "value" variable in URL is getting nothing.Why Is it happening.Is there any wrong in this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the button click, the page will be in the postback state and your condition will be false `if (!IsPostBack)` so it will not enter into the block and hence the value will not be assigned to `strheadlinesid1`

this block

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["folder"].ToString())))
    {
        strheadlinesid1 = Request.QueryString["folder"].ToString();

    }
}
```

should be

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["folder"].ToString())))
    {
        strheadlinesid1 = Request.QueryString["folder"].ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Yeah, and after postback query string doesn't change so just remove `if (!IsPostBack)` condition.

Answer (score 2):

A button click is a postback so `strheadlinesid1` will not be assigned to and will be empty.

You need to remove the check for `IsPostback`, since button click events will usually be executed as postback events.

```
public void Submit1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs E)
{
    string strheadlinesid1 = string.Empty;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["folder"].ToString())))
    {
        strheadlinesid1 = Request.QueryString["folder"].ToString();
    }

    string URL = "view4.aspx?value="+strheadlinesid1;

    Response.Redirect(URL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Button click is a postback and the code to read "folder" query string doesn't execute if it is a postback?

So the value of "value" is always empty.

Remove the check for `!IsPostback` if that is what you wanted.